# React onClick sometimes needs 2 click to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have a toggle function which is needs for the data to change the status from Active to Complete or Complete to Active. However sometimes the onClick button needs 2 clicks in order to change the status of the data.

```js
type Status = "Active" | "Completed";
const [taskState, setTaskState] = useState<Status>("Active");
const handleTaskToggle = async (e: React.MouseEvent, taskId: number) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let error = null;
    if (taskState === "Completed") {
      await activeTask(taskId).catch((err) => (error = err));
      if (!error) {
        refetchActiveTasks();
        refetchCompletedTasks();
        setTaskState("Active");
      } else {
        console.error("Error updating task:", error);
      }
    } else if (taskState === "Active") {
      await completeTask(taskId).catch((err) => (error = err));
      if (!error) {
        refetchActiveTasks();
        refetchCompletedTasks();
        setTaskState("Completed");
      } else {
        console.error("Error updating task:", error);
      }
    }
  };
```

and here's the button that I used:

```js
<button 
    type="button" 
    className="hover:scale-125 transition-transform " 
    onClick={(e) => handleTaskToggle(e, task.taskId)}> 
    {CheckCircle}
</button>
```

I tried to change the method of if else into try catch however it still didnt work.

Comment: There are a decent amount of syntax errors, can you update your code to be free of any random syntax errors?

Comment: Try moving all these:
refetchActiveTasks();
refetchCompletedTasks();
setTaskState("...");

inside the functions `acitaveTask and completeTask` based on the state. You are duplicating the code.

Also, how do you initialize `taskState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a similar code like your case you can see and [run here](https://playcode.io/1761788)

also codes lie as below

```
  const [taskState, setTaskState] = useState('Active');
  const task = {
    taskId: 1,
  };

  const completeTask = taskId => {
    console.log('completeTask ');
  };

  const refetchActiveTasks = () => {
    console.log('refetchActiveTasks ');
  };

  const refetchCompletedTasks = () => {
    console.log('refetchCompletedTasks');
  };
  const activeTask = async () => {
    console.log('activeTask');
  };

  const handleTaskToggle = async (e, taskId) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      if (taskState === 'Completed') {
        console.log('Completed WORK')
        await activeTask(taskId);
        refetchActiveTasks();
        refetchCompletedTasks();
        setTaskState('Active');
      } else if (taskState === 'Active') {
        console.log('Active WORK')
        await completeTask(taskId);
        refetchActiveTasks();
        refetchCompletedTasks();
        setTaskState('Completed');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating task:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <button
        type='button'
        className='hover:scale-125 transition-transform '
        onClick={e => handleTaskToggle(e, task.taskId)}
      >
        Button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Tried to use it but still get the same result. I'll put my whole code for better understanding

Comment: @ArielAgdon you can check